# capacities to do or capacities in doing?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the best choice that can be used after "capacities":

> Do people have capacities to do (I think this is right), or capacities in doing
>   (as a good friend of mine insists)?

For example, can we say that

> Individuals have differential **capacities to invest** in acquiring
>   these skills, depending on their social class.

or

> Individuals have differential **capacities in investing** in acquiring
>   these skills, depending on their social class.

Comment: ["capacities to invest"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capacities+to+invest%2C+capacities+in+investing&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccapacities%20to%20invest%3B%2Cc0) seems to be more common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example combines two gerunds, making it an awkward presentation of thought.  An editor would suggest it be changed to the first example construction (*to invest in acquiring*).  As to the notion of whether "in investing in" or "to invest in" is the preferred usage to follow "capacities," the intention of the noun should be considered.  Given the two opposing examples, "capacities" should be followed by the infinitive verb which is followed by a gerund.  However, if in the second example the second gerund is replaced by a noun of action construction (i.e., *the acquisition of*), then "in investing in" would be correct, but still awkward.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentences you have quoted, "capacities to invest" sounds better. In another context you could say, for example, "He had a great capacity *for saying* the right thing".